# Exporting mongoose model

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I am trying to export the mongoose variable to another JS file but I can't get it to work.

I want to export the user variable which is a mongoose model. If I include the mongoose things directly inte results.js then it will work.

Error:
TypeError: app.user is not a constructor
    at projects\api\js\results.js:12:23

app.js

```
var express = require("express");
var session = module.exports = require('express-session');
var bodyParser = module.exports = require('body-parser');

//MongoDB
var mongoose = require("mongoose");
mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost/time_report");

var userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    password: String
});

var user = mongoose.model("user", userSchema);

var app = module.exports = express();
exports.user = user; //This variable is not reachable
```

---

results.js

```
var app = require("./app.js");

function showDate() {
    app.get("/results", function(req, res) {
        //Get login info
        var uName = req.query.username;
        var pw = req.query.password;

        var newUser = app.user({ //Fail here
            name: uName,
            password: pw
        });

        console.log(newUser.name);

        // Check to match with database
        user.findOne({ name: newUser.name, password: newUser.password }, function(err, user) {
            if (err) return handleError(err);

            if (user) {
                console.log("Logged in");
                //console.log('This is great! %s %s', user.name, user.password);
                res.render("results", { data: newUser });
            } else {
                res.send("Failed to login");
            }

        });
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `app.js`, change this:

```
//...        
var app = module.exports = express();
exports.user = user; //This variable is not reachable
```

with this:

```
//...        
module.exports = {
    app: express(),
    user
}
```

Then, in `result.js` change this line:

```
var app = require("./app.js"); // <----- NO
```

with this other one:

```
var {app, user} = require("./app.js"); // <----- YES
```

And of course, in result.js you want instantiate a new **user** (so don't forget the **new** keyword):

```
var newUser = new user ({ //No longer fails here
    name: uName,
    password: pw
});
```

Comment: Thanks! This is absolutely mind blowing. Is there any JS version where you can use a more reasonable JAVA like syntax?

Comment: I assume you are new to JS. In that case I'd recommend taking some accelerated courses in Javascript (preferably ES6 Javascript). If you are used to JAVA programming, maybe you want to learn TypeScript (which is a strict syntactical superset of JavaScript) enforcing best-practices, helping you to avoid common JS mistakes, and making it "somewhat" similar to other OOP syntaxes (to a certain extent though). However, before jumping straight into TypeScript, I'd take a basic/intermediate course on JS first. Does this make sense?

Comment: It sure does. Will look into this.